# Redirecting to a cutted URL in Pyramid

Tags: python, url, pyramid, pylons, web-frameworks

I got an URL like: http://localhost:4284/?session_expired=true
Now I'm sending and AJAX-Request for something and the return should be a HTTPFound with 'http://localhost:4284/'.
Cutting the URL is not the problem, but either Pyramid or the Browser are ignoring the changes, so the keep the parameter session_expired in the window location :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning an HTTPFound-Object, do not parse it as JSON, but rather parse is as HTML!

Answer (score 1):

AJAX requests do not affect the window location (I suppose you want the browser to go to a completely new page as a result of the AJAX request, so the address in browser's address bar changes).

You can do this manually in JavaScript when handling the response of the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax(
   ...
}.done(function (data) {
    if (data.redirect_to) {
        window.location =  data.redirect_to;
    }
});
```

In the example above the server returned 200 Ok status with a JSON response which looks something like `{"redirect_to": "http://localhost:4284/"}`. You may prefer to return a different HTTP status and handle it in the error handler instead.

Comment: The HTTPFound-type of the Pyramid-Framework is a 302 http redirection and I though this would lead to an redirect. Strange is also, that my page is reloading after ajax has finished, but it ignores the 302. If i have to redirect manually, I'll do so. Thx

Comment: Yes, it does lead to a redirect - but what's getting redirected is your original Ajax request. The HTTP spec requires the browser to transparently follow the redirect and return the result of the resource the redirect points to. So your Ajax handler gets the html contents of the page the redirect points to as the response.